# Why is React only rendering the last two elements in my array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a series of images from a folder. I have managed to do this, but I would like to implement a system where the images go in rows of 2. This has worked, but it seems to be overwriting the other rows, because I only get the last two rendered. I would be very appreciative of any help. Here is my code:

```
var imageArray = [];
var imageCount = 0;
// Obtain the root 
const rootElement = document.querySelector('.containerMain')
// Create a ES6 class component    
    class ShoppingList extends React.Component { 
// Use the render function to return JSX component      
    render() { 
        return (
        <div className="row" key={uuidv4()}>
                {imageArray}
        </div>
      );
      } 
    }

function renderImages() {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ShoppingList/>,
        rootElement
      )
}

var folder = "Images/";
var numberOfImages = 0;

function ajaxRender() {
    return $.ajax({
        url : folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                    if(imageCount===2) {
                        renderImages()
                        imageCount = 0;
                        imageArray = [];
                    } else {
                        imageArray.push(<img src={val} key={val}></img>)
                        imageCount += 1;
                    }
                    console.log(imageArray);
                } 
            });
        }
    });
}

$.when(ajaxRender().done(function(){
    console.log(imageCount)
}));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems you reset `imageArray = [];` each time after you push 2 images into it. Why are you mixing jQuery and React? They are very orthogonal to one another. You should place the `imageArray` into React state and update it via a component lifecycle method, i.e. `componentDidMount`|`componentDidUpdate`. You seem to be missing many React basics.

Comment: `imageArray = [];`

Comment: I think, You are rendering image in same root element which will overwrite old images and you will get last set of images(2)

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, I'm resetting it because I couldn't think of a better way to render every 2 elements.

Comment: Sounds like you just want a 2-column grid layout, i.e. render *all* the images, 2 images per row?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you keep resetting the array every time you put in 2 images? Can't you just make a system where if the image index is an even number, you render on one row, and if the image index is an odd number, it'll render on a row below it possibly?